# How to solve OutOfMemoryException errors when adding a new NuGet package?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget, out-of-memory, assembly-binding-redirect

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13719641/107625), I'm getting an exception in the Package Manager Output window while adding a new NuGet package ([System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable)):

> Failed to update binding redirects for MyProject.csproj : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

While I find many results for [`NullReferenceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception) errors, I found none for my [`OutOfMemoryException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception).

**My question:**

How to solve `OutOfMemoryException` errors when adding a new NuGet package to a project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was:

1. Exit Visual Studio.
2. Start Visual Studio again.
3. Uninstall the package.
4. Install the package again.

After that, no exception was shown in the Package Manager Output window.

I still do have no binding redirects for the package, but maybe it is not required at all.